# How to find all latest distinct tuples in MongoDB/Mongoose

Tags: mongodb

I've got a collection called **Market** where I store prices for items. Every so often, I update the value for an item. In order to keep track of all prices, I insert a new tuple each time a price for an item is changed.

My question is: how do I get the list of distinct items with the last updated price?

**Example**
Current collection

```
[
  { item: 'A', timestamp: '1513555200', price: 10 },
  { item: 'B', timestamp: '1513555200', price: 50 },
  { item: 'C', timestamp: '1513555200', price: 30 },
  { item: 'A', timestamp: '1513814400', price: 14 },
  { item: 'B', timestamp: '1513814400', price: 55 },
  { item: 'A', timestamp: '1514050995', price: 15 },
  { item: 'D', timestamp: '1514050995', price: 150 },
]
```

Desired result:

```
[
  { item: 'A', timestamp: '1514050995', price: 15 },
  { item: 'B', timestamp: '1513814400', price: 55 },
  { item: 'C', timestamp: '1513555200', price: 30 },
  { item: 'D', timestamp: '1514050995', price: 150 }
]
```

Comment: I think you look through the array and get items and then filter them by timestamp...right? Something like this:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/

Comment: @SpencerBigum: kinda. I just don't know how I can filter to get the last for any item.

Comment: I would filter by the timestamp, so you would need to say get all items whose time is greater than X, since time goes up as you move through a timeline.(I think). Using moment.js, you could set a timestamp to which you want to filter by in node or on the client side.

Comment: Sadly, it does not really answer my question. I get the idea though. It will filter out a great deal of items, but the subset stay the same. Here I'll have to use X = 1513555200 to get all the distincts items.
Or, I got it wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into the documentation, I've found the operator [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first) which provide a example solving my question.

```
db.market.aggregate([
  { $sort: {item: 1, timestamp: -1} },
  { $group: {
    _id: "$item",
    timestamp: {$first: "$timestamp"},
    price: {$first: "$price"}
  }}
]);
```

Comment: well I'm glad you were able to figure it out!

Comment: Thanks @SpencerBigum for spending some time trying to solve my problem.

Comment: Also, this is described here "Optimization to Return the First Document of Each Group": https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#optimization-to-return-the-first-document-of-each-group